# Unable to create nginx application on OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to add an nginx application to my Openshift 4.1 project. The ImageStream is available in the openshift namespace as:

```
image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/openshift/nginx
```

When I create the app with:

```
oc new-app nginx
```

The created Pod is in CrashLoopBackOff. From the logs I can read:

```
This is a S2I rhel base image: To use it, install S2I: https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image Sample invocation: s2i build https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-container.git --context-dir=1.12/test/test-app/ rhscl/nginx-112-rhel7 nginx-sample-app You can then run the resulting image via: docker run -p 8080:8080 nginx-sample-app
```

It's not clear to me. Can't I use "oc-new app" to create the application? or do I miss any Environment variable?
Thanks

Comment: `nginx` is an "S2I" container (source-to-image), it's expected to take a Git repository that contains your Nginx configuration, and run it. You can test this by instead running `oc new-app nginx~https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-ex`

Comment: Usage documentation: https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-container/tree/master/1.14

Comment: Thanks for your help!